# Spring Cloud Gateway deletes SESSION cookie after a call to resource server

Tags: session, cookies, session-cookies, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm having a problem with `SESSION` cookie being reset by Spring Cloud Gateway after a call to a resource server.

I have an Angular application, a Spring Cloud Gateway application, an external Authorization Server and a Resource Server of my own.

The Angular application first authorizes via Spring Cloud Gateway app (who delegates this work to external Authorization Server using OAuth2) and receives a `SESSION` cookie. At this point the user is authenticated and `Authentication` object is available in Spring Cloud Gateway app.

Next, the Angular app calls an endpoint of Spring Cloud Gateway app, which actually forwards the call to the Resource Server (and includes the Bearer token in the call, so the call works fine), the Resource server returns some result, which is successfully send back through the Spring Cloud Gateway app to the Angular app. BUT alongside successful response the Spring Cloud Gateway app sends this header:

`set-cookie: SESSION=; Max-Age=0; Expires=Sat, 17 Aug 2019 20:39:44 GMT; Path=/; HTTPOnly`

which kills the cookie on the client side and makes subsequent calls impossible, even though the `Authentication` object is still alive and the session looks to fine as well.

Does anyone know what can be the reason of such behavior?

Comment: gateway does not create cookie's at all, something else is: either the downstream application or spring security or something else, but it is not gateway.

Comment: @spencergibb i'm sorry, i probably wasn't clear enough. I was trying to say that the app that uses `Spring Cloud Gateway` to forward calls from Angular app to resource servers is using Spring Reactive Security and OAuth2 with external auth server, but for some reason invalidates the cookie once a request is forwarded to any of resource servers. I've worked around it by implementing a `GlobalFilter` that removes the header, but would like to know what's the reason for cookie being removed or at least get a clue **what** might be setting the header

Comment: After struggling with the same issue, I found out that disabling `requestCache` in the `ServerHttpSecurity` fixed the issue, and the gateway no longer deleted the `SESSION` cookie. I don't really know why though.

Comment: How do I disable the requestCache? `http.requestCache.disable()` had no effect.

Comment: @horatius please see the answer I provided: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66444832/2578324

Answer (score 6):

We had the ***exact*** issue in our WebFlux resource servers -- the API gateway would proxy a request to a resource server, so the first request worked, but subsequent requests would try to authenticate again because the `SESSION` cookie was cleared out, resulting in some `X-XSRF-TOKEN` errors.

We solved this by adding `.requestCache().requestCache(NoOpServerRequestCache.getInstance())` to our `securityWebFilterChain` bean definition in our WebFlux resource servers.

```
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
class ResourceServerConfiguration {

    @Value('${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.jwk-set-uri}')
    String jwkSetUri

    @Bean
    SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        http
                .csrf().disable()     
                .requestCache().requestCache(NoOpServerRequestCache.getInstance()).and()
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .formLogin().disable()
                .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt().jwkSetUri(jwkSetUri)
                .and().and()
                .authorizeExchange()
                .pathMatchers("/v1/**").authenticated()                
    }
}
```

In the "classic" MVC world, you would configure your `ResourceServerConfigurer` classes like this:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.sessionManagement()
    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
}
```

**Update 11/22/2022**

Our microservice architecture has begun to expand, and we started seeing this issue again on services not owned by our team. Turns out they had stateful web services, meaning, sessions were created when calling them which caused the SESSION cookie to get overridden on the Spring Cloud Gateway client application. We applied this to our configuration to permanently resolve this issue:

```yaml
server:
  reactive:
    session:
      cookie:
        name: SESSION_${spring.application.name}
```

This eliminates an issue where `SESSION` cookies from other web service calls collide with the Gateway client's `SESSION` cookie.

Comment: This actually helped me. I was having an issue with getting the claims out of the JWT. It was basically erasing the data. Once I added this line, the issue went away.

Comment: this took me nearly a full week of headache and finally solved it with this simple entry. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

I had encountered the same case.

Did the external Authorization Server produce a cookie which is base64 encode?
Such as `Set-Cookie: SESSION=YWZjOTc4YmUtOTNmNy00N2UxLTg0NjgtYWJlNWMwZmNiOWUx`

If so, it will cause the problem.

The CookieWebSessionIdResolver defined in Spring Web used by Spring Cloud Gateway does not deal with the base64 encoded cookie values. Instead, it directly uses the raw cookie value to find the corresponding session in the storage. Obviously, no Authentication object will be found. So that Spring Cloud Gateway choose to kill the "invalid" cookie given by the Angular app.

There are two solutions given below.

1. Disable base64 encoding of cookie values in the external Authorization Server if it is also managed by you.
2. Override WebSessionIdResolver to change the default behaviour so as to decode cookie values when reading by session manager. And don't forget to register it as a Spring Bean in your Spring Cloud Gateway implementation.

In my case, Solution 1 was choosen. My Authorization Server uses Spring Security + Spring Session. I changed the default settings of `HttpSessionIdResolver` like this.

```
    CookieHttpSessionIdResolver cookieHttpSessionIdResolver = new CookieHttpSessionIdResolver();
    DefaultCookieSerializer defaultCookieSerializer = new DefaultCookieSerializer();
    defaultCookieSerializer.setUseBase64Encoding(false);
    defaultCookieSerializer.setCookieName("SESSION");
    cookieHttpSessionIdResolver.setCookieSerializer(defaultCookieSerializer);
```

Comment: This answer worked for me. The previous answer based on disabling the request cache worked only for a time but wasn't stable solution. I disabled the base64 session cookie encoding as you suggested int option 1. I didn't find the way to read the cookie value in a `WebSessionIdResolver` to decode a base64 value.